# Is it possible to create fonts (TTF) from SVGs from the command line?

Tags: svg, fonts, font-face, font-awesome, fontforge

I have a set of SVGs I want to turn into a font (TTF) - but it has to be done in an automated fashion - is this possible?

It seems as though fontforge, etc all require some human interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with fontforge:

```
import fontforge

# create an empty font in memory
font = fontforge.font()

# Create a char in the unicode 41 pos (an "A")
glyph = font.createChar(41, 'A')

# Import the glyph info
glyph.importOutlines('/path/to/svg/foo.svg')

# Write the font from memory to a TTF file
font.generate('/output/math/foo.ttf')
```